# How many rows can view (QTreetview/QtableView/QListView) handle

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtreeview

I have come across this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28631) . I am building 64-bit application on Linux, In this case How many rows my view (I am building tree) can handle ?

1. can I change default height (30) to 15 (in this case view can handle more rows than in default height case right ?)

Comment: Why in the world would you want to display 70M rows? And why do you think that row height value change anything in that?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov  I hope you understand my question, I waned to know if there is any limit for QTreeView in displiyng number of rows.

Comment: It's not clear. You want the max number of _visible_ rows?

Comment: since it doesnt render them all at once then it doesnt matter how many you put in (to a limit i suppose) i use one and it can handle hundreds of thousands easily, needs some customising to make it actually do that quickly though but since you render the ones that are visible anything shouldnt be a problem

Comment: @AngryDuck even then we need to provide rowCount in rowCount() function thats where we get into this problem,,, that's what people mentioning in that link.